# jQuery onclick event for <li> tags

Tags: jquery

I have the following menu items generated by a template generator, artisteer:

```
<ul class="art-vmenu">

<li><a href="#" ><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
        <span class="t">Home</span></a></li>    
<li><a href="#" ><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
        <span class="t">Create User</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="#" class="active"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
        <span class="t">List Users</span></a></li>  
<li><a href="#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
        <span class="t">Admin</span></a></li>   
</ul>
```

I want to capture the onclick event for `<li>` with a single jQuery function:
I've tried this which is incomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('ul.art-vmenu li').click(function(e) 
   { 
    alert(this);
   });
});
```

I can go as far as seeing this is a HTMLliElement but cannot figure how to get the menu text or id for it?

How is menu click usually captured with jQuery?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here, to get the text of the menu that triggered the event (does not seem to have any id):

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $('ul.art-vmenu li').click(function(e) 
    { 
     alert($(this).find("span.t").text());
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 8):

In your question it seems that you have `span` selector with given to every `span` a seperate class into `ul li` option and then you have many answers, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('ul.art-vmenu li').click(function(e) 
    { 
     alert($(this).find("span.t").text());
   });
});
```

But you need not to use `ul.art-vmenu li` rather you can use direct `ul` with the use of **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** as used in below example :

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $("ul.art-vmenu").on("click","li", function(){
     alert($(this).find("span.t").text());
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a better answer since it only binds one handler and if the list has more elements included, they'll automatically have the desired behavior instead of having to make sure they also get hooked up when they are added to the page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what your question is, but to get the text of the `li` element you can use:

`$(this).text();`

And to get the `id` of an element you can use `.attr('id');`. Once you have a reference to the element you want (e.g. `$(this)`) you can perform any jQuery function on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ID, or any other attribute, using jQuery's attrib function.

```
$('ul.art-vmenu li').attrib('id');
```

To get the menu text, which is in the t span, you can do this:

```
$('ul.art-vmenu li').children('span.t').html();
```

To change the HTML is just as easy:

```
$('ul.art-vmenu li').children('span.t').html("I'm different");
```

Of course, if you wanted to get all the span.t's in the first place, it would be simpler to do:

```
$('ul.art-vemnu li span.t').html();
```

But I'm assuming you've already got the li's, and want to use child() to find something within that element.

Answer (score 0):

Typing in `$(this)` will return the jQuery element instead of the HTML Element.  Then it just depends on what you want to do in the click event.

`alert($(this));`

Comment: Just learned my issue - I was trying $this instead of $(this) - thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a HTML element.
`$(this)` is a jQuery object that encapsulates the HTML element.

Use `$(this).text()` to retrieve the element's inner text.

I suggest you refer to the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.art-vmenu li').live("click", function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpYSC/

jquery documentation on live(): http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Description: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.