# Why my notification JS is not working? site.js

Tags: javascript

I don't know if I'm missing something. Please help me.
There is my site.js;

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () {
            return $("#notification-content").html();
        },
        html: true
    });

    $('body').append(`<div id="notification-content" class="hide"></div>`)


    function getNotification() {
        var res = "<ul class='list-group'>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/getNotification",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.count != 0) {
                    $("#notificationCount").html(result.count);
                    $("#notificationCount").show('slow');
                } else {
                    $("#notificationCount").html();
                    $("#notificationCount").hide('slow');
                    $("#notificationCount").popover('hide');
                }

                var notifications = result.userNotification;
                notifications.forEach(element => {
                    res = res + "<li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id='" + element.notification.id + "'>" + element.notification.text + "</li>";
                });

                res = res + "</ul>";

                $("#notification-content").html(res);

                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    $("ul").on('click', '.notification-text', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        var id = $(target).data('id');

        readNotification(id, target);
    });

    function readNotification(id, target) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/ReadNotification",
            method: "GET",
            data: { notificationId: id },
            success: function (result) {
                getNotification();
                $(target).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }

    getNotification();

});
```

And there is my notification controller;

```html
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using _02_Entities.Entities;
using _04_Business.Services.Bases;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace _05_MvcWebUI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class NotificationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        public NotificationController(INotificationService notificationService, IUserService userService)
        {
            _notificationService = notificationService;
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public IActionResult GetNotification()
        {
            var user = User.Identity.Name;
            var notification = _notificationService.GetUserNotifications(user);
            return Ok(new { UserNotification = notification, Count = notification.Count });
        }

        public IActionResult ReadNotification(int notificationId)
        {
            _notificationService.ReadNotification(notificationId);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

The notification's cursor is pointer, that's okay. But when I click the notification it readNotification function have to work and the notification is have to be readed, but however it is not working.

Btw, I did try my readNotification action and it's perfectly works. But there is an issue on javascript side.

Comment: can you log if click function is being called?

Comment: I add "console.log("click is working");" this code in:

$("ul").on('click', '.notification-text', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        var id = $(target).data('id');
        console.log("click is working")
        readNotification(id, target);
    }); 

and when I click to a notification, there was nothing on console. So click function is not working I think. @SiddiqueAhmad

Comment: sorry for bad syntax on comment, I'm new at stack overflow:) @SiddiqueAhmad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365255/jquery-onclick-event-for-li-tags this link can help

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad Now it's working when I click the notification navbar item, it has to be working when I click the notifications and notifications are opening when I click the notification navbar.

Comment: I think problem is I cannot link the notification that <li> tag. The li tag has a class="list-group-item notification". And I give that li class named notification to click function but it's not see somehow the <li> tags.

Comment: can you share updated gist

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad I post an answer to explain better. Thanks for trying to help man.

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad I changed Jquery to " $(document).on('click', 'ul li.notification-text', function (e) {} " it's now working when I click to notifications. But it's not passing notification id this time.

Comment: @SiddiqueAhmad I make some progress but cannot get id this time, haha. The new link is here if you want to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691271/why-li-tag-is-not-accept-data-id-attribute-oclock-event-cannot-get-id

Answer (score 0):

İt's the same basically. I add 1-2-3 to some lines to explain better.
1 is  tag.
2 ares  tags.
in the 3 I have to gave the id of "li" tag to click event. And I did but click event does not see "li" tags somehow. Check 2 for "li" tags class, it's "notification-text" and check 3 you will se I gave the "notification-text" to click event but click event is not sees "li" tags.

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () {
            return $("#notification-content").html();
        },
        html: true
    });

    $('body').append(`<div id="notification-content" class="hide"></div>`)


    function getNotification() {
1        var res = "<ul class='list-group'>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/getNotification",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.count != 0) {
                    $("#notificationCount").html(result.count);
                    $("#notificationCount").show('slow');
                } else {
                    $("#notificationCount").html();
                    $("#notificationCount").hide('slow');
                    $("#notificationCount").popover();
                }

                var notifications = result.userNotification;
                notifications.forEach(element => {
 2                   res = res + "<li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id='" + element.notification.id + "'>" + element.notification.text + "</li>";
                });

                res = res + "</ul>";

                $("#notification-content").html(res);

                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

3    $("ul.notifications").on('click', 'li.notification-text', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        var id = $(target).data('id');
        console.log('click function is working.');
        readNotification(id, target);
    });

    function readNotification(id, target) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/ReadNotification",
            method: "GET",
            data: { notificationId: id },
            success: function (result) {
                getNotification();
                $(target).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }

    getNotification();

    let connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/signalServer");

    connection.on('displayNotification', () => {
        getNotification();
    });

    connection.start();

});
```