# Why <li> tag is not accept data-id attribute? O'clock event cannot get id

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

You will see in the below, my "li" tags are not accept and display data-id attribute. Because of that, my click event does not get id and cannot pass the id to action.

I added 1 and 2 some lines to explain better.
1 is where "li" tag is created.
2 is where should get data-id attribute of "li" tag.

Also my jQuery version is 3.5.1

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: function () {
            return $("#notification-content").html();
        },
        html: true
    });

    $('body').append(`<div id="notification-content" class="hide"></div>`)


    function getNotification() {
        var res = "<ul class='list-group notifications'>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/getNotification",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result.count != 0) {
                    $("#notificationCount").html(result.count);
                    $("#notificationCount").show('slow');
                } else {
                    $("#notificationCount").html();
                    $("#notificationCount").hide('slow');
                    $("#notificationCount").popover();
                }

                var notifications = result.userNotification;
                notifications.forEach(element => {
1                    res = res + "<li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id='" + element.notification.id + "'>" + element.notification.text + "</li>";
                });

                res = res + "</ul>";

                $("#notification-content").html(res);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', 'ul.notifications li.notification-text', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
2        var id = $(target).data('id');
        console.log(id);
    });

    function readNotification(id, target) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Notification/ReadNotification",
            method: "GET",
            data: { notificationId: id },
            success: function (result) {
                getNotification();
                $(target).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }

    getNotification();


});
```

Comment: `e.target` is the deepest element that was clicked on, which may be a child of the `<li>` and not the `<li>` itself. Just use `this` in this case, because jQuery will take care of the details and give you the `<li>` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, data-id set as an attribute, and `.data('id')` is used to get the data of element.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'ul.notifications li.notification-text', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
       var id = $(target).attr('data-id');
        console.log(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit must be found elsewhere. `[li].data("id")` works like expected. A [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```js
$(`ul`).append(`
  <li class='list-group-item notification-text' data-id="someId123">
    Some Text
  </li>`);
  
console.log($(`ul li`).data(`id`));
//                     ^ works
```

```css
[data-id]:after {
  content: ' (my data-id is 'attr(data-id)')';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```